# Get last post in loop in Wordpress

Tags: loop

i have a loop in wp

```
<?php
$count = 0; //set up counter variable 
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array( 
            'after'    => array(
                'year'  => 2015,
                'month' => 07,
                'day'   => 15,
                'hour'   => 13,
            ),
            'before'    => array(
                'year'  => 2030,
                'month' => 2,
                'day'   => 28,
            ),
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post__not_in' => array( 9563 ),
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query($args); 
while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); $count++; 
?> 



<div class="ref_projektbox bounceIn refbox<?php echo ($xyz++%2); ?> col-lg-4 newone"> 
    <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );  ?>  
    <div class="newonewrapper">  
        CONTENT
    </div>   
</div>
```

How I can get the last post and put a custom div BEFORE? I´m planning a custom div for the post in 2015 07 15...

do you can help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.